# RabbitMQ - an example for a "Nack" need

Tags: rabbitmq

When do I need to respond with a nack on my RabbitMQ listener?
So far I have never witness an error in the message over the network.

I guess the network layer should take care of it, no?
If I get an error message from the publisher a nack will just leave it in the queue, wont it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A `NACK` could be sent in case the consumer was (maybe temporarily) not able to process the delivery. The messages will be redelivered by the server to any available consumer (potentially including the original) and processing could be tried again.

It is different from `REJECT` in the sense that rejected deliveries are not resend to the rejecting consumer (redelivery happens on a different channel).